Обьединить блоки если они display:flex;
Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать, не знаю даже как правильно в гугле запрос написать. Нужно объединить вот эти 2 блока в один https://prnt.sc/Fi4lnsiXBgvN
Есть 4 блока display:flex


.c_main {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  align-items: center;
  margin: auto;
}

.c_block {
  display: flex;
  background: rgba(255, 208, 96, 0.2);
  border-radius: 16px;
  padding: 16px;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  width: 395px;
  height: 75px;
  margin-top: 15px;
  margin-right: 23px;
}
<div class="c_main">
  <div class="c_block">
    <div class="c_block_1">
      text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="c_block">
    <div class="c_block_1">
      text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="c_block">
    <div class="c_block_1">
      text
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="c_block">
    <div class="c_block_1">
      text
    </div>
  </div>
</div>




Как создать минимальный, самодостаточный и воспроизводимый пример

@rusgeli поправил оформление,  извините

Вместо двух сделать один большой? Или что?

@Effex
Да, но чтобы слева так и осталось два

@ИгорьГоловатый получилось?

@Effex То что нужно, спасибо!

Не забывайте нажимать кнопочку "Ответ полезен" и отмечать ответ как верное решение :)

Не знаю каковая именно нужна была реализация в плане гибкости, но вот так вроде бы соответствует требованию визуально:


.main {
  display: flex;
  gap: 10px;
}

.column {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  gap: inherit;
}

.block {
  display: flex;
  padding: 10px;
  background: rgba(255, 208, 96, 0.2);
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 16px;
  width: 395px;
  height: 75px;
}

.double_block {
  height: 100%;
}
<div class="main">
  <div class="column">
    <div class="block">
      <div>text</div>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
      <div>text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="column">
    <div class="block double_block">
      <div>text</div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>



PS: некоторые стили добавите, если я что-то утерял

То что нужно, спасибо!
